# Javascript - Cookie value gets changed after storing

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have this code to set cookie:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString(), ';path = /';
}
```

And to set cookie i have to call function with all arguments.

```
SetCookie("number", "1", 10);
```

But the cookie value isn't 1 when i use my ReadCookie function get value which is:

```
function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
    var theCookie = "" + document.cookie;
    var ind = theCookie.indexOf(cookieName + "=");
    if (ind == -1 || cookieName == "") return "";
    var ind1 = theCookie.indexOf(";", ind);
    if (ind1 == -1) ind1 = theCookie.length;
    return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind + cookieName.length + 1, ind1));
}
```

Output instead of "1" is:

```
e85751a63874d221ff23323575137233
```

Comment: I tried using your code provided, but this seems to be working fine for me. That output you put in there is coming back for ReadCookie("number"), right?

Comment: Yeah! It was working fine before but now it sucks.

Comment: The code works just fine in my Chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine, but I thought I'd post some code I have written to deal with cookies through JavaScript to give you more ideas about what you can do. I based it on the MDN example [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support), but with the functionality I wanted (object-lookup, cache until change). Feel free to lift pieces of the code (or use it all) for your project.

```
cookie.setItem('number', 1, 10 * 24 * 60 * 60); // expires is Number => seconds
cookie.getItem('number'); // "1"
```

*function* `cookie` makes a *String* correctly formatted for use with `document.cookie`, it takes parameters *key, val, expires, path, domain, secure*. Parameter *expires* can be *Number* (seconds from now or *Infinity*), *Date* or *String*.

*function* `cookie.setItem` has same parameters as `cookie` but also applies it. If only a *key* is given, it is assumed that it is a whole cookie-formatted *String*.

*function* `cookie.getItem` only takes a parameter *key*.

*function* `cookie.removeItem` has parameters *key, path*. You only need to use *key*.

```
var cookie = (function () {
    var cookieString = '',
        items = {},
        expireNever = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 64e10).toGMTString(), // 20 years
        expireNow = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT',
        cookie,
        __update,
        supportsMaxAge = 1;
    __update = function () {
        var a, i, j, o = {};
        cookieString = document.cookie;
        a = cookieString.split('; ');
        i = a.length;
        while (i--) {
            j = a[i].indexOf('=');
            o[decodeURIComponent(a[i].slice(0, j))]
                = decodeURIComponent(a[i].slice(j + 1));
        }
        items = o;
    }
    cookie = function cookie(key, val, expires, path, domain, secure) {
        var s = encodeURIComponent(''+key) + '='
              + encodeURIComponent(''+val);
        if (!key) return '';
        if (expires || expires === 0) {
            switch (expires.constructor) {
                case Number:
                    if (expires === Infinity) expires = 'expires=' + expireNever;
                    else {
                        if (supportsMaxAge) expires = 'max-age=' + expires;
                        else expires = 'expires=' + new Date(new Date().valueOf() + expires * 1000).toGMTString();
                    }
                    break;
                case Date:
                    expires = 'expires=' + expires.toGMTString();
                    break;
                default:
                case String:
                    expires = 'expires=' + expires;
                    break;
            }
            s = s + '; ' + expires;
        }
        if (domain) s = s + '; domain=' + domain;
        if (path) s = s + '; path=' + path;
        if (secure) s = s + '; secure';
        return s;
    };
    cookie.getNames = function () {
        if (document.cookie !== cookieString) __update();
        return Object.keys(items);
    };
    cookie.getItem = function (key) {
        var s;
        if (document.cookie !== cookieString) __update();
        s = items[key];
        if (s || s === '') return s;
        return null;
    };
    cookie.setItem = function (key, val, expires, path, domain, secure) {
        var s;
        if (!key) return null;
        if (val === void 0) s = key;
        else s = cookie(key, val, expires, path, domain, secure);
        document.cookie = s;
        return s;
    };
    cookie.hasItem = function (key) {
        if (cookie.getItem(key) === null) return false;
        return true;
    };
    cookie.removeItem = function (key, path) {
        if (cookie.setItem(key, '', expireNow, path)) return true;
        return false;
    };
    // find out if max-age is supported
    cookie.setItem('test_cookie_max_age', '1', 0);
    if (cookie.getItem('test_cookie_max_age')) {
        supportsMaxAge = 0;
        cookie.removeItem('test_cookie_max_age');
    }
    __update();
    return cookie;
}());
```